# "FormNotFoundError: no form matching name ..." with Mechanize

Tags: python, web-scraping, mechanize

Here's my code:

```
import mechanize

br = mechanize.Browser()
br.set_handle_robots(False)
br.set_handle_refresh(False)
br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Firefox')]

fitchsite = "https://www.fitchratings.com/jsp/general/login/LoginController.faces"
br.open(fitchsite)

br.select_form(name="loginForm")
br.form["loginForm:userName"] = "my username"
br.form["loginForm:password"] = "my password"

r = br.submit()
s = r.read()

print s
```

I'm trying to log in to the website of fitch but get a `formnotfounderror`, although the form is definitely there and has the above-mentioned name.